# Perform google search then get result save in django database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

i am learning Django tutorial, could you pls advise me how to edit cod to get search result to put into database? Below are my cod and sure that the rest of cod in this tutorial i did correctly and test complete, many thanks

I have updated the code as per your request. The result on home page fail is also attached at the bottom of the question section. If you have any additional question, please ask and I will be able to share.

```
def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of a message."""
        date = timezone.localtime(self.log_date)
        return f"'{self.message}' logged on {date.strftime('%A, %d %B, %Y at %X')}"

class HomeListView(ListView):
    """Renders the home page, with a list of all messages."""
    model = LogMessage

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
        
def log_message(request):
    form = LogMessageForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():  
            query = form.save(commit=False)
            for j in search(query, tbs='qdr:h', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2.0):
                message = LogMessage(log_date = datetime.now(), message =j)
                message.save()
        return redirect("home")
    else:
        return render(request, "hello/log_message.html", {"form": form})
```

--- HOME PAGE FAIL INFO

```
TypeError at /log/
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/log/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
Exception Location: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py, line 866, in quote_from_bytes
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.7
Python Path:    
['D:\\Apps\\07.1\\hello_django',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 07 Jan 2021 14:38:11 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
D:\Apps\07.1\hello_django\hello\views.py, line 34, in log_message
            for j in search(query, tbs='qdr:h', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2.0): …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
form    
<LogMessageForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(message)>
query   
<LogMessage: '333321212121121221' logged on Thursday, 07 January, 2021 at 14:38:11>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/log/'>
```

Comment: Can we please see definition of LogMessage in models.py

Comment: from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class LogMessage(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    log_date = models.DateTimeField("date logged")

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of a message."""
        date = timezone.localtime(self.log_date)
        return f"'{self.message}' logged on {date.strftime('%A, %d %B, %Y at %X')}"

Comment: Nononooo don't post it in a comment. Edit your question. Noone can read that

Comment: Dear Guide, i did update question, pls help advise? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
for j in search(query, tbs='qdr:h', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2.0):
            message = LogMessage(log_date = datetime.now(), message =j)
            message.save()
```

Comment: dear guide, pls see my edit questionr after check your advise